# Golang mgo getting greater than and less than timestamps

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I'm trying to query a timestamp that is between two other timestamps. I've got this simple function:

```
func (e *EventService) GetEmployeeEventsBetween(employeeID string, start, end int64) ([]Event, error) {
    var retrivedEvents []Event
    if err := e.c().Find(bson.M{
        "employee": employeeID,
        "start":    bson.M{"$gte": start, "$lte": end},
    }).All(&retrivedEvents); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return retrivedEvents, nil
}
```

Now according to that function the query should only return `"events"` that start date timestamp is greater than the `start` timestamp passed in and less than the `end` timestamp passed in.

However let's say the db has 3 events each with these start dates:

`1474290000` 
`1474389000`
`1474463700`

Now lets say I pass in a `start` param of `1474462800` and `end` param of `1474491600` I would expect that function would only return 1 `"event"` which would be the one with the `1474463700` timestamp however it returns all of them. Pretty much no matter what I pass in as my `start` and `end` params it returns all the items in the db

**UPDATE**:

If I log `.Explain()` this is what I get back

```
bson.M{
    "queryPlanner": bson.M{
    "plannerVersion":1, 
    "namespace":"hairbuddy.events", 
    "indexFilterSet":false, 
    "parsedQuery": bson.M{
        "$and":[]interface {}{
            bson.M{
                "employee": bson.M{"$eq":"57c36bdfe5b07e10ae5526ee"}
            }, 
            bson.M{
                "start":bson.M{"$lte":1474491600}
            }, 
            bson.M{
                "start": bson.M{"$gte":1474462800}
            }
        }
    }, 
    "winningPlan": bson.M{
        "inputStage": bson.M{
            "stage":"COLLSCAN", 
            "filter": bson.M{
                "$and":[]interface {}{
                    bson.M{
                        "employee": bson.M{"$eq":"57c36bdfe5b07e10ae5526ee"}
                    }, 
                    bson.M{
                        "start": bson.M{"$lte":1474491600}
                    }, 
                    bson.M{
                        "start":bson.M{"$gte":1474462800}
                    }
                }
            }, 
            "direction":"forward"
        }, 
        "stage":"LIMIT", 
        "limitAmount":40
    }, 
    "rejectedPlans":[]interface {}{}
    }, 
    "executionStats": bson.M{
        "totalDocsExamined":3, 
        "executionStages": bson.M{
            "restoreState":0, 
            "isEOF":1, 
            "invalidates":0, 
            "inputStage": bson.M{
                "restoreState":0,
                "direction":"forward", 
                "stage":"COLLSCAN", 
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate":0, 
                "works":5, 
                "needYield":0, 
                "nReturned":1, 
                "advanced":1, "isEOF":1, 
                "docsExamined":3, 
                "filter": bson.M{
                    "$and":[]interface {}{
                        bson.M{
                            "employee": bson.M{"$eq":"57c36bdfe5b07e10ae5526ee"}
                        }, 
                        bson.M{
                            "start": bson.M{"$lte":1474491600}
                        }, 
                        bson.M{
                            "start": bson.M{"$gte":1474462800}
                        }
                    }
                }, 
                "needTime":3, 
                "saveState":0, 
                "invalidates":0
            }, 
            "stage":"LIMIT", 
            "advanced":1, 
            "needYield":0, 
            "saveState":0, 
            "limitAmount":40, 
            "nReturned":1, 
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate":0, 
            "works":5, 
            "needTime":3
        }, 
        "allPlansExecution":[]interface {}{}, 
        "executionSuccess":true, 
        "nReturned":1, 
        "executionTimeMillis":0, 
        "totalKeysExamined":0
    }, 
    "serverInfo": bson.M{
        "version":"3.2.7", 
        "gitVersion":"4249c1d2b5999ebbf1fdf3bc0e0e3b3ff5c0aaf2", 
        "host":"rodrigos-MacBook-Pro.local", 
        "port":27017
    }, 
    "ok":1,
}
```

Comment: Can you try replacing `All` with [explain](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Query.Explain) to see exactly what mongo query is being executed.

Comment: after a bit of indenting, if you look at `executionStats.nReturned` the value is 1, so I'd consider cross checking this by using [Count](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Query.Count) in place of `All` to check if it returned 3 or 1.

Comment: @algrebe Wow thank you! After thinking I had gone crazy because count was equal to 1 but when I was checking my api calls it had all the events I realized I had a bug somewhere in my code that ended up calling get all events and returning that

Comment: no problem. I'm not sure how to frame an answer for this though. You probably know best.

Answer (score 0):

```
    filter := bson.D{{Key: "updatedAt", Value: bson.D{{Key: "$lte", Value: time.Date(2009, 11, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.Local)}}},
    {Key: "updatedAt", Value: bson.D{{Key: "$gte", Value: time.Date(2009, 10, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.Local)}}}}
```

Took reference from
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/go/current/fundamentals/crud/read-operations/retrieve/#std-label-golang-retrieve